# jQuery dropdown menu implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How could I make this ( [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/valacheeduard/LwYuz/) ) mega-menu usable?

I want the submenu-1,2 and 3 to stay visible while hovering over them too, and when mouseout of them, they will slideUp.

[Code sample HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/valacheeduard/LwYuz/)

```
$(".menu-1").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu1").stop().slideToggle(700);
});

$(".menu-2").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu2").stop().slideToggle(700);
});


$(".menu-3").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu3").stop().slideToggle(700);
});
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: your code is working ,what is problem?

Comment: It's working fine. Can you tell where is the problem?

Comment: He wants the submenu to display while hovering over it as well! I know its early guys, but read before down voting FFS!

Comment: he should speak something ,HE is not commenting and expecting answers

Comment: @KailashYadav , @Pratik Joshi
Sorry, but I wasn`t expecting this quick answer.
I want to make the submenu visible when hovering over it too. It can`t be used as menu in this actual shape.

Comment: I again ask you => your code is working ,what is problem?

Comment: @user2997779 , u mean submenu hides when i hover over it ?

Comment: cant seem to edit this post, but check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/LwYuz/2/. He wants to be able to click on menu items still... So the sub menu comes out, then as you are going to select a menu item, it goes back in. His question is... "How can I keep the submenu visible on hover as well?"

Comment: @user2997779  , I solved your problem ,and placed live demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live demo working http://jsfiddle.net/LwYuz/3/

```
$(".menu-1").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu1").stop().slideToggle(700);
});


$(".menu-2").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu2").stop().slideToggle(700);
});


$(".menu-3").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu3").stop().slideToggle(700);
});


$(".submenu1").hover(function(){
$(".submenu1").stop().slideToggle(700);    
});

$(".submenu2").hover(function(){
$(".submenu2").stop().slideToggle(700);    
});

$(".submenu3").hover(function(){
$(".submenu3").stop().slideToggle(700);    
});
```

Comment: Yup, that was simple. I was going to do this way too hard than this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can`t upvote, not enough reputation because you guys down-voted my quewstion.

Sorry.

Comment: Now u have 27 Points ,you can do +1 .Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Anyways, enough of my raging in the comment section,

You can use the jquery multiple class selector.

```
  $(".menu-1,.submenu1").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu1").stop().slideToggle(700);
});


$(".menu-2,.submenu2").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu2").stop().slideToggle(700);
});


$(".menu-3,.submenu3").hover(function(){
    $(".submenu3").stop().slideToggle(700);
});
```

Here is your solution ... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwYuz/5/) updated

Comment: u deleted answer,and again added :)

Comment: yeah - I thought I would leave it here, because its slightly more elegant than your one ;)

Comment: Yes it is ,but he had to give him answer before getting too downvoted ,and finally before the Question gets deleted.So i gave Quick solution.He can Optimize it later .Your code is also good

Comment: yeah, people down voting because they can't read. they should remove that down vote option. its stupid!! No question is a silly question.

Comment: See SEE ,your Question just GOT Upvoted !! :) Is this magic, or ITS ME ? You know what you should do now :) comon u have 488 repo ,u can do +1